# Is the initialization of global variable the same as the initialization of static variable inside a function

Tags: c++, static, initialization, static-initialization

I'm trying to figure out all different kinds of initialization in C++. Now I'm reading this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

In the example of this link, we have such a piece of code:

```
std::string s; // zero-initialized to indeterminate value
               // then default-initialized to ""
```

As my understanding, the initialization of the global variable is as below:

When we compile the code, the `s` is zero-initialized, it is put at the `.bss` segment of the binary file. When we run the binary file (meaning that the kernel is starting to load the binary file into RAM), the `s` is default-initialized to the empty string `""`.

Now, we define a function as below:

```
void func()
{
    static std::string s;
}
```

If we call the function first time, the `s` will be initialized, this is for sure. But is it still initialized with two methods: first zero initialization, then default initialization, just like the first `s`?

BTW, I'm working on Ubuntu, X86_64 architecture with the compiler GCC 7.5.
If my question is not standardized by C++, you could tell me in the comment and I'll close this question.

Comment: Case (2) could fall under the _"as-if"_ rule - as you can't observe the state of  `s` before calling `func` then the compiler can do what it likes; and as `s` is not used outside of `func` then there is no need for `s` to even exist.

Comment: C++ has no concept of "segments" or "kernels". If you're wondering how a specific implementation works on a particular platform, please add that information to the question.

Comment: Even on systems that _do_ have segments, it's up to the compiler to decide whether to use them. A variable that's used only in exception handling? Chances are that it's often unused, so an optimizer may decide to allocate storage only on first use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is it still initialized with two methods: first zero
> initialization, then default initialization, just like the first s?

Assuming, the "as-if"-rule effectively forces the compiler to consider the existence of this variable, yes. Excerpts from the standard:

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1. For every named variable with static or thread-local storage
>    duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any
>    other initialization.
>
> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> 1. when a variable with automatic, static, or thread-local storage
>    duration is declared with no initializer;

As molbdnilo said within the comments, you should avoid thinking in terms of binary files, kernel and segments here totally if you are only interested in the behavior the standard claims.